# Understanding this AVR ASM routine

Tags: avr, assembly

This is an abbreviated version of [WS2812 LED control routine](https://github.com/cpldcpu/light_ws2812/blob/master/light_ws2812_AVR/Light_WS2812/light_ws2812.c). I have removed all the no-ops for the sake of readability here. Can someone explain the role of the branch instruction (brne) towards the end of the routine?

```
 asm volatile(
    "       ldi   %0,8  \n\t"
    "loop%=:            \n\t"
    "       out   %2,%3 \n\t"    //  '1' [01] '0' [01] - re  "       sbrs  %1,7  \n\t"    //  '1' [03] '0' [02]
    "       out   %2,%4 \n\t"    //  '1' [--] '0' [03] - fe-low
    "       lsl   %1    \n\t"    //  '1' [04] '0' [04]  "       out   %2,%4 \n\t"    //  '1' [+1] '0' [+1] - fe-high
    "       dec   %0    \n\t"    //  '1' [+2] '0' [+2]
    "       brne  loop%=\n\t"    //  '1' [+3] '0' [+4]
    :   "=&d" (ctr)
    :   "r" (curbyte), "I" (_SFR_IO_ADDR(ws2812_PORTREG)), "r" (maskhi), "r" (masklo)
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable `%0` (`ctr` in the surrounding function) is counting the number of bits in the byte being transmitted. The branch causes the routine to loop until all 8 bits of `%1` (`curbyte`) have been processed.

It looks like you may have removed more than just no-ops. There should be at least one branch based on the value of a bit in `%1` that selects one of two paths through the body of the loop. The `out` instructions toggle an output pin high and low to create the PWM waveform that the WS2812 requires, and the no-ops control the relative timing of the high and low periods.

Ah, yes. Looking at the original code, it has:

```
asm volatile(
"       ldi   %0,8  \n\t"
"loop%=:            \n\t"
"       out   %2,%3 \n\t"    //  '1' [01] '0' [01] - re
[ variable number of NOPs based on w1_nops ]
"       sbrs  %1,7  \n\t"    //  '1' [03] '0' [02]
"       out   %2,%4 \n\t"    //  '1' [--] '0' [03] - fe-low
"       lsl   %1    \n\t"    //  '1' [04] '0' [04]
[ variable number of NOPs based on w2_nops ]
"       out   %2,%4 \n\t"    //  '1' [+1] '0' [+1] - fe-high
[ variable number of NOPs based on w3_nops ]
"       dec   %0    \n\t"    //  '1' [+2] '0' [+2]
"       brne  loop%=\n\t"    //  '1' [+3] '0' [+4]
:   "=&d" (ctr)
:   "r" (curbyte), "I" (_SFR_IO_ADDR(ws2812_PORTREG)), "r" (maskhi), "r" (masklo)
);
```

The pin gets set high at the beginning of the loop. The `sbrs` instruction (Skip if Bit in Register is Set?) determines whether the pin gets set low after the `w1_nops` period, or not until after the `w2_nops` period as well. The total of `w1_nops` + `w2_nops` + `w3_nops` (plus the instructions shown here) determines the total period of each bit.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is my first time reading ASM seriously and your comments helped a lot. Making a whole lot more sense now than 2 days ago!